# Error message when using: groupby('').transform(pd.rolling_sum, window=30)

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, transform, rolling-computation

why would this:

```
df2['rollsum'] = df2.groupby('ID')['yes'].transform(pd.rolling_sum, window=30, min_periods=1)
```

Raise the error: "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'rolling_sum'"??
Also, i tried

```
df2['rollsum'] = df2.groupby('ID')['yes'].rolling(30).mean()
```

which gives me this error: "TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index"

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `pd.rolling_sum` has been depreciated, what you can do is:

```
df2['rollsum'] = df2.groupby('ID')['yes'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(30).sum())
```

or

```
df2['rollsum'] = df2.groupby('ID')['yes'].rolling(30).sum().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

The `reset_index` will allow index alignment when assigning the column